# Send an email via email delivery service to Facebook friends

Tags: facebook, email, sendgrid

I am trying to send an email to my Facebook friends using email delivery service (Sendgrid). However, it seems like Facebook is denying the delivery of the email. Sendgrid is showing that my email has been delivered successfully, but no email has been received.

Does anyone had the same issue? Alternatively, can you give me an advice on this? Basically, what I need to achieve is to send emails to Facebook friends using PHP.

Comment: How exactly is Facebook blocking your emails?

Comment: I suppose you are talking about the username@facebook.com email addresses? Those are explicitly meant as a way of user-to-user communication, and are _not_ to be used by apps. So, if you want the user to actively send something to their friends, use the Send dialog. If, on the other hand, you just want to send emails/messages to all their friends automatically – then please stop spamming.

Comment: Thanks, CBroe. Looks like I didn't realize that it's not possible to send emails automatically to @facebook.com emails